# UDP C++ Server and C# Client not receiving

Tags: c#, c++, udp

This is my first time using UDP sockets in windows so please be merciful!
I am trying to set a UDP socket between a C++ console app in windows and a UWP (Universal Windows App) in C#. When I send data from the console to the UWP everything works well. On the other hand, when I am trying to send data from the C# UWP to the console I do not receive anything.
Now I did some monitoring with Wireshark and it seems that the packets are well sent and received by the console IP. Does someone know what am I missing here?

Please find attached the C# UWP client code:

```
        static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("App Started...");
        while (true)
        {
            SendData("test");
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static IPAddress addr = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.40");
    static IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(addr, 27000);
    static UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient(27000);

    static void SendData(string text)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);
            int sendBytes = udpClient.Send(data, data.Length, ep);
            Console.WriteLine("Data sending..." + text);
        }
    }
```

And here's my C++ Console App code:

```
#include <iostream>
// UDP
#define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#include <thread>         
#include <chrono> 
#include <string>
#pragma comment (lib, "ws2_32.lib") // Authomatically include the lib

int main()
{
// Local Variable definitions

std::cout << "\t\ --------------- UDP Server --------------- " << std::endl;
std::cout << std::endl;

WSADATA    WinSockData;
int        iWsaStartup;
int        iWsaCleanup;

SOCKET     UDPSocketServer;
struct     sockaddr_in UDPClient;

char       Buffer[512];
int        iBufferLen = strlen(Buffer) + 1;

int        iBind;
int        iReceiveForm;

int        iUDPClientLen = sizeof(UDPClient);
int        iCloseSocket;

// STEP-1 Startup Winsock
iWsaStartup = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &WinSockData);
if (iWsaStartup != 0)
{
    std::cout << "Can't start Winsock: " << iWsaStartup << std::endl;
}
std::cout << "WSAStartUp Success" << std::endl;

// STEP-2 Fill the UDPClient(SOCKET ADDRESS) Structure
UDPClient.sin_family = AF_INET;
UDPClient.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.40"); 
UDPClient.sin_port = htons(27000);

// STEP-3 Socket creation
UDPSocketServer = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
if (UDPSocketServer == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    std::cout << "Socket Creation Failed, ERROR No: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
}
std::cout << "Socket Success" << std::endl;

// STEP-4 Bind the server
iBind = bind(UDPSocketServer,
             (SOCKADDR*)&UDPClient,
             sizeof(UDPClient));
if (iBind == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    std::cout << "Binding Failed, ERROR No: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
}
std::cout << "Binding Success" << std::endl;

// STEP-5 RecvFrom Fun from receive data from client
while(true)
{
    iReceiveForm = recvfrom(UDPSocketServer,
                            Buffer,
                            iBufferLen,
                            MSG_PEEK,
                            (SOCKADDR*)&UDPClient,
                            &iUDPClientLen);
    if (iReceiveForm == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        std::cout << "Receiving failed, ERROR No: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "Receiving Success" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Received data --> " << Buffer << std::endl;
}

// STEP-6 CloseSocket Function
iCloseSocket = closesocket(UDPSocketServer);
if (iCloseSocket == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    std::cout << "Socket Closing Failed, ERROR No: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
}
std::cout << "WSASocket closing success" << std::endl;

// STEP-7 WSACleanUp Fun for terminating from DLL
iWsaCleanup = WSACleanup();
if (iWsaCleanup == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    std::cout << "WSA CleanUp Failed, ERROR No: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
}
std::cout << "WSA CleanUp Success" << std::endl;

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
```

Comment: You use different ports in your apps: server binds to port 27000 but client tries to reach the server at port 27100. This cannot work.

Comment: That's going to absolutely flood the network, with the same data over and over

Comment: Sorry @SteffenUllrich and thanks for your comment: my bad, the port is the same in the two applications: still not reciving anything.

Comment: Hello @Charlieface , thanks for your comment also! I have a IMU camera stream that I would like to access with very low latency. How could I avoid to flood the network?Thanks!

Comment: No idea, but you probably don't want to be sending text, and you *definitely* don't want to send the same message again and again. I would imagine you need some kind of `async/await` pattern to wait for enough bytes to come through to send a message.

Comment: The number of bytes and frequency in which they  are packaged and sent via UDP can be dealt via an async/await pattern indeed! Thanks @Charlieface for the suggestion. Before that, it seems I have a much more fundamental problem because I cannot even read one package from my c++ console app.